# How to push an existing Eclipse project to GitHub?

Tags: eclipse, github

Currently I'm developing some applications that I want to share with the community using GitHub.

I've found a lot of tutorials on how to create a GitHub repository from scratch, but I couldn't find one for sharing an existing Eclipse project. I would prefer a solution that works inside Eclipse using a GUI.

Answer (score 13):

You can follow this [user guide section of git push (to a GitHub repo)](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Push_Upstream), adding a remote with the ssh address of your GitHub repo:

[image: GitHub Egit ssh]

See also [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html#github_push) to push your local project to that GitHub repo.

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to github create new repository
2. Copy http URL from github
3. Go to Eclipse --> Right click on project --> Team--> share project--> Create 
   new Git Repo.
4. Go to Git Staging--> add to index --> commit and push
5. Right click on Git Repositories push to up stream
6. Paste your http URL of githun which you copy in step 2
7. Enter username and password of github -- > Finish

Answer (score 0):

Also to the answer of [VonC](https://superuser.com/a/423964/178739) i have add the urls in text so if you need to do c&p:

```
remote name: origin
URI: git@github.com:wavemakerIsAwesome/MyAwesomeAppWavemaker.git
host: github.com
```

you can get this uri from git.hub in the repository that you must create :)

NOTE: I use the https connection, providing my git's username and password.

Comment: Hey and welcome to Super User! If you have anything to add to another user's answer, you can propose an edit to his answer or comment on it. There's no need to a separate answer as I see the situation here.